# std::adjacent_difference

Tags: c++, algorithm

I'd like to use `std::adjacent_difference`. My assignment prescribes using algorithms from the header `<algorithm>` (no other headers for algorithm, only this one)

I have found that `std::adjacent_difference` in is `<algorithm>` (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm)

But when I compile my program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
//#include <numeric> it is commented because I should use only `<algorithm>`

int main() {
  std::vector<unsigned int> v;
  v.push_back(1);
  v.push_back(2);
  std::adjacent_difference(v.begin(), v.end(), v.begin());
  for (std::vector<unsigned int>::iterator it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); it++)
    std::cout << *it << "  ";
  return 0;
}
```

with `c++ -std=c++98 main.cpp`, the compiler answers:   ‘adjacent_difference’ is not a member of ‘std‘.

Coud you explain this?

Comment: It works with `<numeric>`, but for this  assignment, I have no right to use other headers except `<algorithm>` for the algorithms

Comment: Cppreference is pretty clear about `std::adjacent_difference`: *Defined in header `<numeric>`*.

Comment: *I have no right to use other headers except `<algorithm>` for the algorithms* - Then you can't use `std::adjacent_difference`.

Comment: Yes. Does it mean that there is an error on the page https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm ?

Comment: The documentation gives you several possible implementations in the `Possible implementation` section: [https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/adjacent_difference#Version_1](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/adjacent_difference#Version_1) Although with that said I expect your professor to want you to write your own code.

Comment: @ak, there is no error on https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm. It states that `adjacent_difference` is Defined in header <numeric>.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm is a list of algorithm functions, if you want the contents of the algorithm header see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/algorithm

Comment: I am not obliged to use specifically `adjcent_difference`, it just suits very well for my code. I will use other functions from `<algorithm>`. But if the information on  en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm is correct and I can use somehow`adjcent_difference` with the header `<algorithm>` only, my code will be beautiful.

Comment: Thank you, I see now, en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm telles that adjacent_difference is defined in header `<numeric>`

Comment: Thank you, I see now the difference between en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm and  en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/algorithm

Comment: @ak It just so happens that `std::adjacent_difference` algorithm is in the `<numeric>` header.  This is not an error.  So is your professor wrong, thinking that `std::adjacent_difference` and *all* algorithms are in the `<algorithm>` header, and then gave you this assignment using this wrong assumption?  You need to clear this up with the professor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comments, I see now the difference:

- en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm is about functions-algorithmes of c++ in general
- en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/algorithm is about the header `<algorithm>`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).